# How to determine if the combobox selectionchangecommitted was raised by keyboard or mouse input

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-2.0

I want the ignore the up and down arrow keys on the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event of a combo box and only have the mouse allow selection. Does anyone know how to do this?

I need a way to determine whether key or click caused the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event. I guess I could have a flag that turns on in a mouseclick event and off in a key down, but I wondered if there was a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the key by using the `KeyDown` event like this;

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to handle the `KeyPress` event for your combobox, and cancel (`e.Canceled = true;`) it. This will also prevent the combobox item from changing when you hit a key that matches the first letter of an item.